# Angular $q Service - Limiting Concurrency for Array of Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, concurrency, angular-promise

Might help to give a bit of background context for this problem: I'm building an angular service that facilitates uploading chunks of multipart form data (mp4 video) to a storage service in the cloud.

I'm attempting to limit the number of unresolved promises (`PUT` requests of chunk data) happening concurrently. I am using `$q.all(myArrayOfPromises).then()...` to listen for all chunk upload promises being resolved, and then return an asynchronous call (`POST` to complete the file) when that happens. I think I'm encountering a race condition with my algorithm, because `$q.all()` gets called before all jobs have been scheduled for files with a lot of chunks, but succeeds for smaller files.

Here's my alogorithm.

```
var uploadInChunks = function (file) {
   var chunkPromises = [];
   var chunkSize = constants.CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES;
   var maxConcurrentChunks = 8;
   var startIndex = 0, chunkIndex = 0;
   var endIndex = chunkSize;
   var totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
   var activePromises = 0;

   var queueChunks = function () {
      while (activePromises <= maxConcurrentChunks && chunkIndex < totalChunks) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         chunkCancelers.push(deferred); // array with broader scope I can use to cancel uploads as they're happening

         var fileSlice = file.slice(startIndex, Math.min(endIndex, file.size));

         chunkPromises.push(addChunkWithRetry(webUpload, chunkIndex, fileSlice).then(function () {
           activePromises--;
           queueChunks();
        });

        activePromises++;
        startIndex += chunkSize;
        endIndex += chunkSize;
        chunkIndex++;
     }
  }

  queueChunks();

  return $q.all(chunkPromises).then(function () {
     return filesApi.completeFile(file.fileId);
  });
};
```

Even though `$q.all` is called prematurely, the chunks of the file that are still pending / not even scheduled at that time are eventually executed and resolved successfully.

I've done a fair amount of reading about throttling the concurrency of `$q` and know there are libraries out there to assist, but I'd really like to have an understanding of why this does not work all of the time :)

Comment: Be careful with `promise.all`, as it doesn't guarantee to settle promises, based on a race condition. Only `promise.settle` guarantees to settle them, if it is available in your promise library (not in AngularJS). I recently started on my own solution for this: [spex](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise that you're returning (`$q.all`) isn't really indicative of the promise you actually want to return.  In your code above, the returned promise will finish after the first `maxConcurrentChunks` get resolved, because that's how many promises are in `chunkPromises` when you pass it to `$q.all()`.

Another way to handle this (and get the result you want) would be the following psuedocode:

```
var uploadInChunks = function(file){

    //...vars...
    var fileCompleteDeferral = $q.defer();

    var queueChunks = function(){
        chunkPromises.push(nextChunk(chunkIndex).then(function () {
            activePromises--;

            if(allChunksDone()) { //could be activePromises == 0, or chunkIndex == totalChunks - 1
                fileCompleteDeferral.resolve();
            }
            else {
                queueChunks();
            }
        });
    }

    return fileCompleteDeferral.promise.then(completeFile());
}
```

The promise returned by this code will only resolve after ALL the promises are done, rather than just the first 8.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes sense now that I look at it. I was only deferring the first 16 chunks (first 8 + `promise.then( queueChunks() )`)